# Do I expand my SKU data fields in a mysql table for easy/efficient queries?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm a beginner trying to set up a database structure for a few million records.

My SKU format looks like this:

```
DESIGN   LOCALITY  PRODUCT  TYPE  GENDER   COLOR
234324    45454     100      VN     M        BL
```

Example table:

```
SKU | DESCRIPTION | SIZE
```

I don't really need separate MySQL table columns for each of the fields within the SKU, as they are all contained within the SKU and can be stored in 1 column named SKU.

Yet, will this make my job of doing queries much more difficult and inefficient?  Should I setup 1 column for each of the fields within the SKU?

Example table 2:

```
SKU | DESIGN | LOCALITY | PRODUCT | TYPE | GENDER | COLOR | DESCRIPTION | SIZE
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect to ever search the table on a subset of the components of the SKU?  E.g., "select * from [table name] where Locality = 45454"?

Comment: Yes, I plan on doing queries on each field within the SKU.

Comment: Yes. Much more difficult and inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to query against the individual components of your SKU field, I recommend storing each component in a separate column.  If you want to include the entire SKU as a field as well (as your "table 2" example suggests), I recommend making it a calculated column.  Otherwise you could have update anomalies.

I would also recommend indexing each column individually, but there are others who will recommend a single index that includes all the fields.  This is the subject of much debate in database-design circles :).

Comment: Single-column versus multi-column ("composite") indexes optimize _different_ queries.  It's not a debate, it's a fact.

Comment: @RickJames, yes, that is a fact that comes up in the larger debate of whether one should create many single-column indices or a few composite indices (a debate which I will not engage further here).